# How to grab the surrounding td elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so i have this html structure [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujDsS/) and what I want do is grab all 8 surrounding tds when one is clicked.

So for example if the user clicks on #c3 then I want an array of the ['b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c2', 'c4', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'] but if they select #a2 since it doesnt have 8 surrounding corners it would return ['a1', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3']

This is the direction I was going with but I think this will get pretty complicated ...any better ideas or is this the best way

```
function surrounding_table_rows(id){
  var table_rows = new Array();
  var letters = new Array("a","b","c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o");
  var letter = id[0];
  var number = id[1];
  var index = letters.indexOf(letter);
  if (index == 0) {
    // need to add this logic here
  }else{
    var prior_letter = letters[index - 1];
    var after_letter = letters[index + 1];
  if (number == 0) {
    // need to add this logic here
    }else if(number == 14){
      // need to add this logic here
    }else{
      table_rows.push("#"+letter+(parseInt(number)-1));
      table_rows.push("#"+letter+(parseInt(number)+1));
      table_rows.push("#"+prior_letter+(parseInt(number)-1));
      table_rows.push("#"+prior_letter+(number));
      table_rows.push("#"+prior_letter+(parseInt(number)+1));
      table_rows.push("#"+after_letter+(parseInt(number)-1));
      table_rows.push("#"+after_letter+(number));
      table_rows.push("#"+after_letter+(parseInt(number)+1));
    }

  }
  return table_rows;
}
```

my javascript function does work on middle

```
surrounding_table_rows("d4")
["#d3", "#d5", "#c3", "#c4", "#c5", "#e3", "#e4", "#e5"]
```

here is the html

```
 <table class='config'>
              <tr>
                <td id='a1'></td>
                <td id='a2'></td>
                <td id='a3'></td>
                <td id='a4'></td>
                <td id='a5'></td>
                <td id='a6'></td>
                <td id='a7'></td>
                <td id='a8'></td>
                <td id='a9'></td>
                <td id='a10'></td>
                <td id='a11'></td>
                <td id='a12'></td>
                <td id='a13'></td>
                <td id='a14'></td>
                <td id='a15'></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id='b1'></td>
                <td id='b2'></td>
                <td id='b3'></td>
                <td id='b4'></td>
                <td id='b5'></td>
                <td id='b6'></td>
                <td id='b7'></td>
                <td id='b8'></td>
                <td id='b9'></td>
                <td id='b10'></td>
                <td id='b11'></td>
                <td id='b12'></td>
                <td id='b13'></td>
                <td id='b14'></td>
                <td id='b15'></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id='c1'></td>
                <td id='c2'></td>
                <td id='c3'></td>
                <td id='c4'></td>
                <td id='c5'></td>
                <td id='c6'></td>
                <td id='c7'></td>
                <td id='c8'></td>
                <td id='c9'></td>
                <td id='c10'></td>
                <td id='c11'></td>
                <td id='c12'></td>
                <td id='c13'></td>
                <td id='c14'></td>
                <td id='c15'></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id='d1'></td>
                <td id='d2'></td>
                <td id='d3'></td>
                <td id='d4'></td>
                <td id='d5'></td>
                <td id='d6'></td>
                <td id='d7'></td>
                <td id='d8'></td>
                <td id='d9'></td>
                <td id='d10'></td>
                <td id='d11'></td>
                <td id='d12'></td>
                <td id='d13'></td>
                <td id='d14'></td>
                <td id='d15'></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id='e1'></td>
                <td id='e2'></td>
                <td id='e3'></td>
                <td id='e4'></td>
                <td id='e5'></td>
                <td id='e6'></td>
                <td id='e7'></td>
                <td id='e8'></td>
                <td id='e9'></td>
                <td id='e10'></td>
                <td id='e11'></td>
                <td id='e12'></td>
                <td id='e13'></td>
                <td id='e14'></td>
                <td id='e15'></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id='f1'></td>
                <td id='f2'></td>
                <td id='f3'></td>
                <td id='f4'></td>
                <td id='f5'></td>
                <td id='f6'></td>
                <td id='f7'></td>
                <td id='f8'></td>
                <td id='f9'></td>
                <td id='f10'></td>
                <td id='f11'></td>
                <td id='f12'></td>
                <td id='f13'></td>
                <td id='f14'></td>
                <td id='f15'></td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: There's another way to do it, but the error I can immediately spot is that if you use eg: `e10` as a target element, your `var number = id[1];` will not return `10` but `1` :)

Comment: Can you use a library? Otherwise it might possibly work using document.querySelector and using css3 to not select everything but that item, otherwise you'll have to get the parent and filter the children etc.

Comment: yes you can use a library.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a rudimentary solution to your problem, using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/ujDsS/9/

```
$(function() {
 $("td").css("cursor","pointer").click(function() {
     $("td").css("background","white");
     var $i, $j;
     var cell = $(this), parentRow = cell.parent(), container = parentRow.parent();
     var x = parentRow.children("td").index(cell), y = container.children("tr").index(parentRow);
     var myID = cell.attr("id");

     for ($i = -1; $i <= 1; $i++) {
        if (y-$i < 0) continue;
        var row = container.children("tr").eq(y-$i);
        if (!row.length) continue;

        for ($j = -1; $j <= 1; $j++) {
            if (x-$j < 0) continue;
            var cell2 = row.children("td").eq(x-$j);
            if (!cell2.length) continue;
            cell2.css("background","red");
         }
       }
   });
});
```

What I am doing is pretty simple: on each click, I convert the cell into its x-y coordinates, and then loop through the 8 neighbors + itself and paint them red.

jQuery has an issue (it's a feature, really) where the indices of `eq` can be negative. Fixing this is left as an exercise - it's as simple as checking if y-$i is negative :-)

This assumes one thing: You will not use `colspan` or `rowspan`

Comment: +1 for the *exercise* (please include the code in your Answer)

Comment: what is this line         var cell = $(this), parentRow = cell.parent(), container = parentRow.parent(); and this line         var x = parentRow.children("td").index(cell), y = container.children("tr").index(parentRow);

Comment: Its very different syntax then normal

Comment: @Trace: he is using a library called `jQuery` that simplifies html manipulation and standardizes quite a bit of the javascript/css between browsers.

Comment: No i know jquery very well...but what I dont know is this syntax         var cell = $(this), parentRow = cell.parent(), container = parentRow.parent(); what are all the commas for

Comment: @Trace the commas are just a way to skip writing var var var :) that means: `var a=1; var b=2;` === `var a=1, b=2;`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Added the checks. Trace, the `var x,y,z;` notation allows me to define multiple variables in one go.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld "one go" is more readable if splitted in multiple lines.